# Calling up html text box using javascript and converting it to an integer

Tags: javascript, html

So I just want to understand how I could do this, very simple example:

My html is

```
<div id = "pie"> eee </div>

<input type="text" name="item1" size="5">
```

and my javascript is

```
var q = parseFloat("10");

document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = q ;
```

and basically what I want to do is call up whatever text is in the text box (named item1) and convert it to an integer, then display that number. I'm sure there's an easy way to do it but I cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
+(document.getElementsByName('item1')[0].value);
```

That is the shortest way to do that now to display it, for an example in the element `#pie`

```
document.getElementById('pie').innerHTML = +(document.getElementsByName('item1')[0].value)
```

Putting `+` before something will convert it to a number. If the text box isn't a number you can detect that by:

```
var value = document.getElementsByName('item1')[0].value;

document.getElementById('pie').innerHTML = !isNaN(value)?+value:"Not a number";
```

## [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6dz960we/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of item 1

```
var item1_value = parseInt(getElementsByName('item1')[0].value);
```

Display the value of item1 in pie

```
document.getElementById('pie').innerHTML = item1_value;
```

Comment: that would be perfect, but as part of my task is to not edit the html of the text box. Is there any way to pull up the text box by anything other than id?